# Cannot find underground jungle temple

Tags: terraria

Cannot find the jungle temple in terraria. We have scoured our map for hours.[image: As you can see, there is no temple in our jungle and that is the only jungle on our map.]
Please help us!

Comment: Was this world generated after the 1.2 patch was released?

Answer (score 1):

Your jungle does not contain a jungle temple.

Either your world was generated pre 1.2 patch or there is bug and your world was generated without a temple.

The only way to get into a temple will be to generate a new world and go find the temple there.